# Attempting to connect to LDAP using django-python3-ldap but the target machine is actively refusing it

Tags: python, django, active-directory, ldap

I am working on a django app and attempting to use `django_python3_ldap` to connect to my company's LDAP and AD. I followed the docs basic settings in my `settings.py` but when I try doing `python manage.py ldap_sync_users` I get this error

```
LDAP connect failed: ('unable to open socket', [(datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 25, 12, 25, 36, 77877), <class 'ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPSocketOpenError'>, LDAPSocketOpenError('socket connection error while opening: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made bec
ause the target machine actively refused it',), ('::1', 389, 0, 0)), (datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 25, 12, 25, 37, 78809), <class 'ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPSocketOpenError'>, LDAPSocketOpenError('socket connection error while opening: [WinError 10061] No connect
ion could be made because the target machine actively refused it',), ('127.0.0.1', 389))])
CommandError: Could not connect to LDAP server
```

Here is my settings.py file

```
import os
import ldap
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch, GroupOfNamesType, NestedActiveDirectoryGroupType

# Baseline configuration.
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://***.**.***.**"
LDAP_AUTH_CONNECTION_USERNAME = 'usr@ab.com'
LDAP_AUTH_CONNECTION_PASSWORD = '*******'

# The LDAP search base for looking up users.
LDAP_AUTH_SEARCH_BASE = "ou=people,dc=example,dc=com"

# The LDAP class that represents a user.
LDAP_AUTH_OBJECT_CLASS = "user"

# Keep ModelBackend around for per-user permissions and maybe a local
# superuser.
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_python3_ldap.auth.LDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
DEBUG = True

LDAP_AUTH_USE_TLS = False


# User model fields mapped to the LDAP
# attributes that represent them.
LDAP_AUTH_USER_FIELDS = {
    "username": "sAMAccountName",
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "sn",
    "email": "mail",
}


LDAP_AUTH_FORMAT_USERNAME = "django_python3_ldap.utils.format_username_active_directory_principal"
LDAP_AUTH_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_DOMAIN = "ab.com"


LDAP_AUTH_USER_LOOKUP_FIELDS = ("username",)

LDAP_AUTH_CLEAN_USER_DATA = "django_python3_ldap.utils.clean_user_data"

LDAP_AUTH_SYNC_USER_RELATIONS = "django_python3_ldap.utils.sync_user_relations"

LDAP_AUTH_FORMAT_SEARCH_FILTERS = "django_python3_ldap.utils.format_search_filters"
```

but I don't think this is a config issue because from all the google post and SO posts I've seen it seems like this is the company firewall blocking my access? Or that the `LDAP_AUTH_CONNECTION_USERNAME` I'm using doesn't have permission? Is there any other way that this could happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that a server (either the domain controller, or something in the middle) is stopping the connection. It could be that there is no network connectivity to the domain controller.

On Windows, you can test network connectivity with this in PowerShell, using your domain name in place of "domain.com"

```
(New-Object Net.Sockets.TcpClient).Connect("domain.com", 389)
```

No output means it succeeded. If it fails, it will tell you with a big red error message.

If that does not work, try one of these others. AD LDAP can work on any one of 4 ports:

- 389: LDAP - reads/writes to a single domain - this is the default if you don't specify a port
- 636: LDAP over SSL - same as 389, but encrypted
- 3268: Global catalog - read-only to your AD forest (if you have more than one domain, otherwise it's no different than 389, except read-only)
- 3269: Global catalog over SSL

If one of the other ports work, you can specify it in your code, usually like this: "LDAP://domain.com:3268"

I know AD, but I don't know python that well, so I can't help you with specifics.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was thinking too but I don't quite understand why I can establish a connection through a single sign-in authentication, so if I do a sign in with 

conn = ldap.initialize('ldap://192.168.122.64') # the IP address of the Windows Server
>>> conn.protocol_version = 3
>>> conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
>>> conn.simple_bind_s('Administrator@mooctest.local', 'yourpassword') # an account to test
(97, [], 2, []) 

it works but then get this error when I put it on my app? Any ideas on why?

Comment: I just noticed this now, but the exception has this in it: `('127.0.0.1', 389)`. It seems it's not using that 192 IP you just gave.

Comment: that 192 IP address was just for example that was not my  actual IP , but does that mean that whatever IP i've been providing it's not using that IP address? So I've been providing the wrong IP address?

Comment: I can't say if you're giving it the wrong IP, but it seems to be trying to connect to the local machine. The only way that would work is if you're running this on a domain controller.

Comment: Have you tried using the domain name (`LDAP://domain.com`) rather than an IP?

Comment: I haven't yet because it denies access from unrecognized IP addresses but I will try that tmrw for sure!

Comment: I tried this morning through power shell and was able to connect(It didn't return any error message). But I tried to use my `domain.com` to connect in my app, it still says the same error message.

Comment: Is it still showing `127.0.0.1` in the error message?

Comment: yes it is showing this message `[WinError 10061] No connect
ion could be made because the target machine actively refused it',), ('127.0.0.1', 389))])`

Comment: Are you running this on your domain controller?

Comment: I think I have found the problem, I was not running on the domain where my ldap was located. Thank you for your help!